# Excel dynamic hyperlink via formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink, excel-2003

I am trying to create a hyperlink from one worksheet to another. The worksheet is large and there are many hyperlinks to places all over the other worksheet so I am trying to do this with a formula that I can copy/paste.

Here's what I have:

```
=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDEX('Test Results'!A:A,MATCH("TestCase-001",'Test Results'!A:A,0))),"TestCase-001")
```

The URI that it evaluates to is: `'[Test Results 1.xls]Test Results'!$A$17`, and `A17` on the `Test Results` worksheet is indeed the correct cell to link to. The problem is when I click the hyperlink so I can just to test case details, I get an error saying "Cannot open the specified file", and I'm not sure why since the URI looks correct. Any ideas out there to help me fix this?

Using Excel 2003.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CELL("address",... function returns in the format '[workbook]worksheet'!cell (as you say)

However, HYPERLINK expects [workbook]'worksheet'!cell (note the position of the ' marks) where worksheet name includes spaces.

Simplest answer would be to remove the spaces from the sheet names...

Comment: Ok I think I got it working - I also had to remove dashes (`-`) from the file name and replace them with underscore.

Answer (score 0):

> The CELL("address",... function returns in the format '[workbook]worksheet'!cell (as you say)
>
> However, HYPERLINK expects [workbook]'worksheet'!cell (note the position of the ' marks) where worksheet name includes spaces.
>
> Simplest answer would be to remove the spaces from the sheet names...

Figuring out why those two functions wouldn't work together was some great detective work!

Armed with that knowledge, I actually found a way to force the formatting from the response of the CELL function into the format that the HYPERLINK function expects/requires:

```
    =HYPERLINK("[Workbook.xlsx]'Worksheet'!"&CELL("address", A10), "LinkLabel")
```

Without the full quotes, my version of office (2010) kept truncating the Workbook and Worksheet names because they were referring to the same sheet the code itself was being written in.